# Who are the Asuras/Rakshasas Malyavan says Vishnu has slain?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, puranas, asuras, war

The [Sixth Chapter](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/itihaas/ramayana/valmiki-ramayana-text-with-translation/vol-iv/chapter-06/topic-1) of the Uttarakanda tells about how the devas, unable to withstand the torture of Malyavan, Mali and Sumali, the three sons of Sukesha, rushed to Lord Shiva and then to Lord Vishnu for protection.

Upon hearing this, Malyavan relates what happened to his brothers. In connection he says this:

[image]

Now I know Hiranyakashipu was killed by Lord Narasimha, Namuchi was killed together by Vishnu and Indra using sea foam, Kalanemi and Samhrada were killed during the Samudra Mathana battle.

But who are **Radheya** (the **son of Radha**), Bahumayi(I think this is a description of Radheya), Lokapala, **Yamala and Arjuna** (who as far as I know are Nalakubara and Manigriva who were freed during **Krsnavatara** Yugas later), Hardikya (isn't Kritavarma called Hardikya) and **Shumbha  and Nishumbha** (who were killed by **Durga**)?

None of these asuras seem to be present prior to Malyavan (and he can't be predicting the future), so are they like some other asuras than those whom I have mentioned in brackets?

Most of all, who is **Radheya, the son of Radha** (NOT Karna)?

Comment: [This Page](http://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Puranas/Puranic_Encyclopedia/M.htm) has some info.

Comment: @TheDestroyer That is the Puranic Encyclopedia and it lists the same characters as I have mentioned in brackets after each asura's name.

Comment: Nice question @Surya would be interesting to get an answer! BTW just a thought, the mention of these later names may also be another pointer towards Uttar Kand being a much later addition to the corpus.

Comment: @Dr. Vineet But which interpolator in his right mind would add these names that too in the words of Malyavan?

Comment: Beats me @Surya in fact even the mention of the tribes of Shakas and Yavanas in the Baal Kaand begs the same question!